# Mysql and Php (Could not enter data)

Tags: php, mysql

I need assistance to what might be causing this error, I get this error everytime I have single inverted commas in the data I am trying to post to the database. (field name: abtext)

**Error message:**

> Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'dsf'ds'f'ds'fds'f'ds'f'dsfds','fdsfdd'fd''fds'f'dsf'ds fd 'fds'f'df'ds ds''fd'sf' at line 3

**Data entered to the db:**

field name: (abtext) of type text

data entered on the field=

fdsfdd'fd''fds'f'dsf'ds fd 'fds'f'df'ds ds''fd'sf'ds'f'dsfds'sdf

**My insert code:**

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO poster
          (titlepaper,abtext,authorTitle1,authorName1,authorIntials1,authorSurname1,authorJt1,authorcompany1,authoremail1,authornumber1,presenting1,additional,authorTitle2,authorName2,authorIntials2,authorSurname2,authorJt2,authorcompany2,authoremail2,authornumber2,presenting2,correspondence,authorTitle3,authorName3,authorIntials3,authorSurname3,authorJt3,authorcompany3,authoremail3,authornumber3,presenting3)

          VALUES ('$titlepaper','$abtext','$authorTitle1','$authorName1','$authorIntials1','$authorSurname1','$authorJt1','$authorcompany1','$authoremail1','$authornumber1','$presenting1','$additional','$authorTitle2','$authorName2','$authorIntials2','$authorSurname2','$authorJt2','$authorcompany2','$authoremail2','$authornumber2','$presenting2','$correspondence','$authorTitle3','$authorName3','$authorIntials3','$authorSurname3','$authorJt3','$authorcompany3','$authoremail3','$authornumber3','$presenting3')";

       mysql_select_db('database');
       $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

       if(! $retval ) {
          die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
       }
```

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Stop using mysql_* functions. They're removed in PHP7, and deprecated in previous versions. Switch to mysqli or PDO, and take advantage of prepared statements and bind parameters. That will take care of any issues with escaping data.

Comment: echo the query in the php page.

Comment: I think by 2030 we won't code like this anymore.

Comment: @Drew You're very optimistic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO individual
          (titlepaper,abtext,authorTitle1,authorName1,authorIntials1,authorSurname1,authorJt1,authorcompany1,authoremail1,authornumber1,presenting1,additional)

          VALUES ('". mysql_escape_string($titlepaper) . "','" . mysql_escape_string($abtext) . "','" . mysql_escape_string($authorTitle1) . "','" . mysql_escape_string($authorName1) . "','" . mysql_escape_string($authorIntials1) . "','" . mysql_escape_string($authorSurname1) . "','" . mysql_escape_string($authorJt1) . "','" . mysql_escape_string($authorcompany1) ."','" . mysql_escape_string($authoremail1) . "','" . mysql_escape_string($authornumber1) . "','" . mysql_escape_string($presenting1) . "','" . mysql_escape_string($additional) . "')";
```

This worked! THANKS ALOT GUYS MUCH APPRECIATED!

Answer (score 0):

Please try by using : `htmlspecialchars($abtext)`

so your sql query would be like,

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO poster
        (titlepaper,abtext,authorTitle1,authorName1,authorIntials1,authorSurname1,
        authorJt1,authorcompany1,authoremail1,authornumber1,presenting1,additional,
        authorTitle2,authorName2,authorIntials2,authorSurname2,authorJt2,authorcompany2,
        authoremail2,authornumber2,presenting2,correspondence,authorTitle3,authorName3,
        authorIntials3,authorSurname3,authorJt3,authorcompany3,authoremail3,
        authornumber3,presenting3)

        VALUES
        ('$titlepaper','htmlspecialchars($abtext)','$authorTitle1','$authorName1',
        '$authorIntials1','$authorSurname1','$authorJt1','$authorcompany1',
        '$authoremail1','$authornumber1','$presenting1','$additional',
        '$authorTitle2','$authorName2','$authorIntials2','$authorSurname2',
        '$authorJt2','$authorcompany2','$authoremail2','$authornumber2',
        '$presenting2','$correspondence','$authorTitle3','$authorName3',
        '$authorIntials3','$authorSurname3','$authorJt3','$authorcompany3',
        '$authoremail3','$authornumber3','$presenting3')";
```

Comment: This will insert the text `htmlspecialcharacters(fdsfdd'fd''fds'f'dsf'ds fd 'fds'f'df'ds ds''fd'sf'ds'f'dsfds'sdf)` into the field.

Comment: I think it should work otherwise, it required to use other option like listed below:   
'".$titlepaper."','".htmlspecialchars($abtext)."','".$authorTitle1."' and so on..

Comment: My point is that you have to break out of the string and concatenate to use functions.

Comment: I've tried your suggestions but with no luck. This is what I currently have: $sql = "INSERT INTO individual
        (titlepaper,abtext,authorTitle1,authorName1,authorIntials1,authorSurname1,authorJt1,authorcompany1,authoremail1,authornumber1,presenting1,additional)
        
        VALUES ('".$titlepaper."','".htmlspecialchars($abtext)."',' ".$authorTitle1."','".$authorName1."','".$authorIntials1."','".$authorSurname1."','".$authorJt1."','".$authorcompany1."','".$authoremail1."','".$authornumber1."','".$presenting1."','".$additional."')";   I still get the same error  . Thanks

Comment: Please replace htmlspecialchars with addslashes in your sql query above..

Comment: VALUES ('". mysql_escape_string($titlepaper) . "','" . mysql_escape_string($abtext) . "','" . mysql_escape_string($authorTitle1) . "','" . mysql_escape_string($authorName1) . "','" . mysql_escape_string($authorIntials1) . "','" . mysql_escape_string($authorSurname1) . "','" . mysql_escape_string($authorJt1) . "','" . mysql_escape_string($authorcompany1) ."','" . mysql_escape_string($authoremail1) . "','" . mysql_escape_string($authornumber1) . "','" . mysql_escape_string($presenting1) . "'"; Used this format and it worked. Thanks for help Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$sql = " INSERT INTO poster(titlepaper,abtext,authorTitle1,authorName1,authorIntials1,authorSurname1,authorJt1,authorcompany1,authoremail1,authornumber1,presenting1,additional,authorTitle2,authorName2,authorIntials2,authorSurname2,authorJt2,authorcompany2,authoremail2,authornumber2,presenting2,correspondence,authorTitle3,authorName3,authorIntials3,authorSurname3,authorJt3,authorcompany3,authoremail3,authornumber3,presenting3)
                     VALUES (" . mysql_escape_string($titlepaper) . "," . mysql_escape_string($abtext) . "," . mysql_escape_string($authorTitle1) . "," . mysql_escape_string($authorName1) . "," . mysql_escape_string($authorIntials1) . "," . mysql_escape_string($authorSurname1) . "," . mysql_escape_string($authorJt1) . "," . mysql_escape_string($authorcompany1) . "," . mysql_escape_string($authoremail1) . "," . mysql_escape_string($authornumber1) . "," . mysql_escape_string($presenting1) . "," . mysql_escape_string($additional) . "," . mysql_escape_string($authorTitle2) . "," . mysql_escape_string($authorName2) . "," . mysql_escape_string($authorIntials2) . "," . mysql_escape_string($authorSurname2) . "," . mysql_escape_string($authorJt2) . "," . mysql_escape_string($authorcompany2) . "," . mysql_escape_string($authoremail2) . "," . mysql_escape_string($authornumber2) . "," . mysql_escape_string($presenting2) . "," . mysql_escape_string($correspondence) . "," . mysql_escape_string($authorTitle3) . "," . mysql_escape_string($authorName3) . "," . mysql_escape_string($authorIntials3) . "," . mysql_escape_string($authorSurname3) . "," . mysql_escape_string($authorJt3) . "," . mysql_escape_string($authorcompany3) . "," . mysql_escape_string($authoremail3) . "," . mysql_escape_string($authornumber3) . "," . mysql_escape_string($presenting3) . ")";

            mysql_select_db('database');
            $retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

            if (!$retval) {
                die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
            }
```

i have changed insert area of insert command. Used mysql_escape_string for escaping unwanted char in insertion variables.

Comment: You should explain what you changed instead of just throwing up some code.